# Sum of two minimal direct summands

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, noncommutative-algebra

It is known by Brauer Lemma that every minimal left ideal $I$ of a ring $R$ is either nilpotent (in fact $I^2=0$) or $I=Re$, where $e^2=e\in R$. Is it true that the sum of two minimal left ideals $Re$ and $Rf$ each generated by idempotents $e$ and $f$ is again generated by an idempotent?  In von Neuman regular rings it is the case.
Maybe it is so when the intersection of these is zero!

Any help would be appreciated!